# Is there a code snippet editor for Intellij Idea 13?

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, ide

Visual Studio has [Snippet Designer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/B08B0375-139E-41D7-AF9B-FAEE50F68392) extension available for creating and managing custom code snippets. Is there something like this extension for Intellij Idea 13, or a way to simply add custom code snippets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no extension that I'm aware of (and I'm not familiar with Snippet Designer), but that functionality exists in IntelliJ Idea.

Hit Preferences and start typing to find "Live Templates". Expand one of the existing ones to see some of the available functionality. You can set tab stops, cursor position, references to local variables. It's very handy.

Comment: I ended up finding Intellij's "Live Templates" shortly after I posted this question. Here's the link in case it is a help to someone else: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/live-templates.html @yalestar Thanks for your answer.